# Predict new samples with PyTorch model

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am newbee in neural networks, i have teached my model and now i want to test it. I have wrote a code with google help, but it do not work.
The problem is that i do not understand from where i am getting the 4th dimension.

**Code is the following:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(32),
    transforms.CenterCrop(32),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])

main_path = 'D:/RTU/dataset/ready_dataset_2classes'
train_data_path = main_path + '/train'
#test_data_path = main_path + '/test'
weigths_path = 'D:/RTU/dataset/weights_done/weights_noise_original037-97%.pt'

train_data = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_data_path, transform=transform)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # convolutional layer (sees 32x32x3 image tensor)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, 3, padding=1)
        # convolutional layer (sees 16x16x16 tensor)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, padding=1)
        # convolutional layer (sees 8x8x32 tensor)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, padding=1)
        # max pooling layer
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        # linear layer (64 * 4 * 4 -> 500)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * 4 * 4, 500)
        # linear layer (500 -> 10)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 250)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(250, 2)  
        # dropout layer (p=0.25)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.25) #0.25

    def forward(self, x):
        # add sequence of convolutional and max pooling layers
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv3(x)))
        # flatten image input
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 4 * 4)
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # add 1st hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        # add dropout layer
        x = self.dropout(x)
        # add 2nd hidden layer, with relu activation function
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)       
        return x

# Disable grad
with torch.no_grad():
    
    # Retrieve item
    index = 1
    item = train_data[index]
    image = item[0]
    true_target = item[1]
    
    # Loading the saved model
    mlp = Net()
    optimizer = optim.SGD(mlp.parameters(), lr=0.01)
    epoch=5
    valid_loss_min = np.Inf
    checkpoint = torch.load(weigths_path , map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
    mlp.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
    epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
    valid_loss_min = checkpoint['valid_loss_min']
    mlp.eval()
    # Generate prediction
    prediction = mlp(image)
    
    # Predicted class value using argmax
    predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction)
    
    # Reshape image
    #image = image.reshape(28, 28, 1)
    
    # Show result
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.title(f'Prediction: {predicted_class} - Actual target: {true_target}')
    plt.show()
```

The code seems working till the "mlp.eval()" and then i am getting an error **Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [16, 3, 3, 3], but got 3-dimensional input of size [3, 32, 32] instead**.
What i am doing wrong?
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXNFg.png)

Comment: Are you using grayscale or colour images? Your network seems to expect three channels, probably for R,G,B, but is getting only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are training neural nets, you are feeding small batches of input data to your model. Indeed even it's not clearly specified when writting Layers in *Pytorch*, If you look at the documentation, [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) you can see that Layers receive **4D arrays**

> [image] with N corresponding to batch size and C to number of channels, here 3 because you are using RGB images

So when testing your model once trained, the testing data should  be built the same way to be fed into the network.

Thus if you want to feed 1 image to your network you must reshape it proprely

```
myimage.reshape(-1,3,32,32)
print(myimage.shape)
#(1,3,32,33)
```

Comment: I have added image = image.reshape(-1,32, 32, 3) before the mlp.eval() and now getting another error - RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 32, 32, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 32 channels instead

Comment: Yes, because it probably should be (batch_size,channels, H_image,W_image), so (1,3,32,32), i have edited my answer. (The solution could have been found just by reading the link i posted..)